# Moviepy - audio gets corrupted when extracted from video

Tags: python, moviepy

a simple code like this is creating a corrupted audio file for some reasons:

```
from moviepy import *

clip = VideoFileClip("cut.mp4")
audio = clip.audio
audio.to_audiofile('temp-audio.mp3')
```

**Expected Behavior**
Audio should be the same as the audio in the video

**Actual Behavior**
audio is corrupted in the end (repeats the end segment a few times like a broken record)

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem:**

Run the code above on [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26500236/149655475-bdd9ffa6-69dc-4d6b-ad32-5789907e42ca.mp4) video with latest moviepy version (don't make fun it's just a trial lol) and you will get this audio which is corrupted (I compressed it in a zip):
[here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/files/7876708/temp-audio.zip)

**Specifications**

Python Version: Python 3.9.9

Moviepy Version: 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this will help you

```
from moviepy import *

clip = VideoFileClip("cut.mp4").subclip(0,1) 
#subclip mean video duration its from the place to start to the end
audio = clip.audio
audio.to_audiofile('temp-audio.mp3')
```

**I hope I've been helpful**

Comment: why/how is that supposed to solve the issue?

Comment: it just remove the repeats by set duration

Comment: That worked, thanks! I still don't understand why it took the wrong audio from the original one though (this subclip thing is not dynamic - I want the entire audio of the any given clip)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by ffmepg incorrectly reporting the duration of the audio.
This causes `iter_chunks` in `AudioClip` to try to read frames outside the length of the file. In `FFMPEG_AudioReader` `get_frame` reads the end of the file again, resulting in a glitch.
For me, the fix was to set the env var `FFMPEG_BINARY=/usr/bin/ffmpeg` to use ffmpeg 6.0 from my system instead of ffmpeg 4.2.2 from inside imageio_ffmpeg